# Request an object other than a string from the user (with completion)

Tags: completion

I have a list of objects and I want the user to pick one of them (with completion). But these objects are a priori not strings, so I can't use completing-read. What should I do ?

**Example** In the following example I want to write the interactive spec for killing a process, so I want the user to pick a process to kill.

```
(defun yf/kill-process (process)
  (interactive (list (let ((list
                            (mapcar
                             (lambda (proc)
                               (cons (format "%s" proc) proc))
                             (process-list))))
                       (cdr
                        (assoc (ido-completing-read "Process: "
                                                    (mapcar #'car list))
                               list)))))
  (when (yes-or-no-p (format "You are about to kill process \"%s\", continue? " process))
    (delete-process process)))
```

This is something I have to do often, so I'm wondering if there's a standard way to achieve this functionality (or if I should write my own... which I have done already, but it's ugly).

Answer (score 1):

You can change your code to get the process's *name* with
`process-name`, so your `let` block:

```
(let ((list
       (mapcar
        (lambda (proc)
          (cons (format "%s" proc) proc))
        (process-list))))
        ...
```

becomes:

```
  (let ((list (mapcar #'process-name (process-list))))
    ...)
```

There's no need to give `delete-process` both the string name and
the name, because, it will work with just the string.  According to
the docstring:

> Delete PROCESS: kill it and forget about it immediately.
>   PROCESS may be a process, a buffer, **the name of a process or
>   buffer**, or nil, indicating the current buffer's process.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed in this specific example, I can use the name as a unique identifier, but I'd like a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own is probably your best bet, you can likely clean up your own version using a supplied function to determine what information to prompt the user with. In this case using a hash table as your collection type may be cleaner.

Consider the solution below as a generic way to prompt for objects:

```lisp
(defun completing-read-by (fn prompt list &rest args)
  "Apply FN to each element of LIST and prompt the user to select a resulting value.
The output of the function will be the corresponding element of LIST

ARGS will be passed to `completing-read' after the PROMPT and COLLECTION arguments."
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table :test 'equal)))
    (mapc (lambda (elem) (puthash (funcall fn elem) elem hash)) list)
    (gethash (apply 'completing-read prompt hash args) hash)))


;; read process by name
(completing-read-by 'process-name "Process: " (process-list) nil t)

;; read a list of structs by property
(defstruct person name age)

(let ((people (list (make-person :name "Bob" :age 22) 
                    (make-person :name "Tom" :age 33)
                    (make-person :name "Jan" :age 34))))
  (completing-read-by 'person-name "Person: " people))
```

Comment: Indeed that works, and I guess a hash table is better than an alist. However I'm wondering if there's a variant on `completing-read` which returns an arbitrary object. It would be nice to support the same range of COLLECTION types as completing-read does (though I have no usecase for it beyond plain lists, so I guess IAGNI).

Answer (score 1):

The general idea is this, for prompting a user to choose an object other than a string: Use a name for the object.

1. Pass an alist `COLLECTION` argument to `completing-read` (you can alternatively use another kind of `COLLECTION` argument - the same approach applies). The cars of the alist entries are the object names; the cdrs are the complete objects (or any parts of them).
2. After the user makes a choice of an object name, `completing-read` returns it, as a string.  You can use the string to look in the alist for the associated object.

In this case, you can use `completing-read` with the process names, and you can keep other process info associated with the names.  For example, use the name, user, and pid in a list as an alist entry:

```el
(setq my-alist
      (mapcar (lambda (pid)
                 (let ((ats  (process-attributes pid)))
                  `(,(cdr (assoc 'comm ats))
                    ,(cdr (assoc 'user ats))
                    ,(number-to-string pid))))
                 (list-system-processes)))
```

That alist lets you use the process names (commands) as completion candidates. You can then look up the associated information (the `user` and the `pid`).

```el
(let* ((name    (completing-read "Choose process: " my-alist))
       (object  (assoc name my-alist))
       (user    (cadr object))
       (pid     (caddr object)))
  (message "Name: %s, User: %s, PID: %s" name user pid))
```